# If value for a column is Nat, update it by subtracting two dates

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame which looks like this:

[image]

What I am trying to do is check if days_diff is NaT using numpy and pandas, if it is NaT then update it by subtracting "2016-01-01" by outofservicedatetime. After running code below:

```
df[['days_diff']] = np.where(pd.isnull(df[['days_diff']]), df[['outofservicedatetime']] - np.datetime64('2016-01-01'), df[['days_diff']])
```

I get output which looks like this:

[image]

How can I have days_diff value as days? Or if anyone can suggest an easier way to achieve this would be equally helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df['days_diff'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['days_diff'])
```

But better is use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for set values by condition:

```
date = pd.to_datetime('2016-01-01')
df.loc[df['days_diff'].isnull(), 'days_diff'] = df['outofservicedatetime'] - date
print (df)
   windturbineid outofservicedatetime    subsystem days_diff
0         wtg_11           2016-03-09  Transformer   68 days
1         wtg_29           2016-03-14      Gearbox   73 days
2         wtg_14           2016-03-22    Converter   81 days
3          wtg_4           2016-03-25    Converter   84 days
4         wtg_19           2016-03-30    Converter   89 days
5         wtg_13           2016-04-05       Yawing   95 days
6          wtg_9           2016-05-04    Converter  124 days
7         wtg_15           2016-05-24    Converter  144 days
8          wtg_7           2016-05-25    Converter  145 days
9         wtg_22           2016-05-30    Generator  150 days
10         wtg_2           2016-05-31    Converter  151 days
11         wtg_1           2016-06-29    Converter  180 days
12         wtg_1           2016-07-11    Generator  192 days
13        wtg_14           2016-07-17    Converter  117 days
14         wtg_7           2016-08-11    Converter   78 days
15        wtg_14           2016-08-22  Transformer  234 days
16         wtg_7           2016-08-25       Yawing  237 days
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get about a factor of two speed improvement over `[df.loc[df['days_diff'].isnull()...` here by using `pd.Series.fillna`, optionally with the argument 'inplace=True' to replicate the behavior of `df.loc`.

```
date = pd.Timestamp('20160101')

df = pd.date_range('20160301', '20160831', freq='7D').to_series().reset_index()

df[0] = [pd.Timedelta('nat')]*25+[pd.Timedelta(days=99), pd.Timedelta(days=45)]

df.columns = ['outofservicedatetime', 'days_diff']

df
Out[258]: 
   outofservicedatetime days_diff
0            2016-03-01       NaT
1            2016-03-08       NaT
2            2016-03-15       NaT
3            2016-03-22       NaT
4            2016-03-29       NaT
5            2016-04-05       NaT
6            2016-04-12       NaT
7            2016-04-19       NaT
8            2016-04-26       NaT
9            2016-05-03       NaT
10           2016-05-10       NaT
11           2016-05-17       NaT
12           2016-05-24       NaT
13           2016-05-31       NaT
14           2016-06-07       NaT
15           2016-06-14       NaT
16           2016-06-21       NaT
17           2016-06-28       NaT
18           2016-07-05       NaT
19           2016-07-12       NaT
20           2016-07-19       NaT
21           2016-07-26       NaT
22           2016-08-02       NaT
23           2016-08-09       NaT
24           2016-08-16       NaT
25           2016-08-23   99 days
26           2016-08-30   45 days


%timeit df['days_diff'].fillna(df['outofservicedatetime']-date)
1.29 ms ± 41.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

df['days_diff'].fillna(df['outofservicedatetime']-date)
Out[260]: 
0     60 days
1     67 days
2     74 days
3     81 days
4     88 days
5     95 days
6    102 days
7    109 days
8    116 days
9    123 days
10   130 days
11   137 days
12   144 days
13   151 days
14   158 days
15   165 days
16   172 days
17   179 days
18   186 days
19   193 days
20   200 days
21   207 days
22   214 days
23   221 days
24   228 days
25    99 days
26    45 days
Name: days_diff, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
%timeit df.loc[df['days_diff'].isnull(), 'days_diff'] = df['outofservicedatetime'] - date
2.46 ms ± 106 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```